# Problems linking an iOS 6 project that uses the facebook SDK for iOS (3.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I'm getting the following error when I try to build my iOS 6 project:

```
file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/.../FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK for architecture armv7s
```

This problem is suposed to be solved updating the facebook sdk to version 3.1. But I updated it and i'm still having the same problem...

Some idea? Is there some trick to update the facebook sdk?

Thanks a lot,

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook SDK has a static library that was not compiled for the new iPhone 5 armv7s architecture. This is why you would receive the "slice" error message. You need to either get a new build of the FB SDK or make sure that you have cleaned your build since there might be residual files that Xcode is seeing.

Comment: When you say "cleaned your build", you mean Product\Clean build foder, don't you? I did it, and I get the same error...